# How can I get all indexes including a data attribute after sorting sortable elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've currently implemented a jQuery sortable. I'm looking now for a way to get all indexes and additional data of all 2 connected list elenents within one array after each drag'n'drop. The array should looks like this:

```
let arrayOfObjects = [
    {
        index: 0, //Should be the index of an element
        identifier: 0, //Should be the data-id of each element
        parent_id: 0 //Should be the data-parent-id of the dropped ul
    }
]
```

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
 $( "#first, #second" ).sortable( {
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  stop: function ( event, ui ) {
      //Maybe here?
  }
 } );
} );
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

ul:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1.12.1/ui/widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-sortable@1.0.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="first" class="sortable" data-parent-id="1">
        <li data-id="1" class="element">1</li>
        <li data-id="2" class="element">2</li>
        <li data-id="3" class="element">3</li>
        <li data-id="4" class="element">4</li>
        <li data-id="5" class="element">5</li>
        <li data-id="6" class="element">6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="second" class="sortable" data-parent-id="2">
        <li data-id="7" class="element">1</li>
        <li data-id="8" class="element">2</li>
        <li data-id="9" class="element">3</li>
        <li data-id="10" class="element">4</li>
        <li data-id="11" class="element">5</li>
        <li data-id="12" class="element">6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do this? When I log my array, I'm expecting all elements as objects in my array with all needed parameters. I've tried a lot, used `ui.item.index()` but wasn't successful.

Comment: Build the array at the point it's required. You also don't need to store the index  as a property of the object, as the object is already at that index in the parent array.

Comment: I need this after every drag'n'drop, so within the stop function I think. And what do you mean with index? I need the index to save it into my database. So I need this data within my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *index: 0, //Should be the index of an element* In the example below, `index` will be set to the element's position in the parent `ul`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function getArr() {
    return $("li").map(function() {
      return {
        index: $(this).index(),
        identifier: $(this).data("id"),
        parent_id: $(this).parent().data("parent-id")
      }
    }).get();
  }

  let arrayOfObjects = getArr();

  console.log(arrayOfObjects);

  $("#first, #second").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      arrayOfObjects = getArr();
      console.log(arrayOfObjects);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

ul:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui@1.12.1/ui/widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-sortable@1.0.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="first" class="sortable" data-parent-id="1">
    <li data-id="1" class="element">1</li>
    <li data-id="2" class="element">2</li>
    <li data-id="3" class="element">3</li>
    <li data-id="4" class="element">4</li>
    <li data-id="5" class="element">5</li>
    <li data-id="6" class="element">6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="second" class="sortable" data-parent-id="2">
    <li data-id="7" class="element">1</li>
    <li data-id="8" class="element">2</li>
    <li data-id="9" class="element">3</li>
    <li data-id="10" class="element">4</li>
    <li data-id="11" class="element">5</li>
    <li data-id="12" class="element">6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When I move the mapping into the stop function, everything dies. Why? I need to build the array dynamically after each list change like written above.

Comment: Ahh, maybe we should use .attr() instead of .data()+

Comment: @Mr.Jo This will do that, it calls the `getArr` function inside the `stop` function. You can use the `Run code snippet` button to see that.

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry. I made a mistake on my side. Thanks for your help! It's working great.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the object you're looking for:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]");

const listItems = Array.from(list).map((item, i) => ({
  index: item.dataset.id,
  identifier: i,
  parent_id: item.parentNode.dataset.parentId
}));
```